# TFS Release Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

I am a developer. While working in TFS, Everytime access getting denied from the drop folder after the successful build during release. But when I redeployed it got succeed. I am helpless Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the drop folder permission as I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Check the shared Properties of the drop folder to see whether it has been granted to everyone or your team the Write/Read permission. I assume the drop folder is only shared to you.

[image]